# Showing wifi network doesn't work depending on building env

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

This question is a bit generic about building app with xcode for IOS phone

I'm a Go backend engineer but recently my company had its mobile app developed by an agency (with React-Native) and we received the source code.

Until now, the builds they made had everything working.

On my side, my company asked me to change some icons and redo a build for the app store.

In the app, we have a screen that allow you to connect to a wifi you're already connected to or list available networks:

```
@implementation WifiManager

//export the name of the native module as 'Wifi' since no explicit name is mentioned
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

//exports a method getCurrentWifiName to javascript
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getCurrentWifiName:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback){
  @try{
    NSString *wifiName = nil;
    NSArray *interFaceNames = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();

    for (NSString *name in interFaceNames) {
      NSDictionary *info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)name);

      if (info[@"SSID"]) {
        wifiName = info[@"SSID"];
      }
    }
    callback(@[[NSNull null], wifiName]);
  }
  @catch(NSException *exception){
    callback(@[exception.reason, [NSNull null]]);
  }
}

@end
```

But those interface (wifiname, interfacenames) are always nil when I compile for release with my xcode (Version 10.1 (10B61))

So my question is, as a non-ios developper, what are the things I should look for here when building with xcode? 
Is there a parameter to check / uncheck? Also, I've found on a website that `CNCopySupportedInterfaces` isn't supposed to work on IOS12, but depending on the build (the agency / mine) it works or not.

Anyone could explain a bit what's happening?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the *Access WiFi Information* capability in your project.

Navigate to the project settings, choose the "Capabilities" tab and enable the option:

[image]

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know React so I can't comment on the implementation but as a general rule, the simulator is not going to give you accurate feedback on anything network-related. There are ways to simulate certain network conditions to allow for rough testing of network-heavy operations but the simulator is nothing but a macOS app so it's still limited to the underlying architecture and its sandbox.

This is a long way of saying, you should be testing this on a real device.